# Rails query that sorts based on the count of a nested model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models: Group & GroupMember

I would like to return Groups, sorted by the highest GroupMember Count? How do you setup this type of join/query count in Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Life is so much easier with counter_cache:

```
$ rails g migration add_group_member_counts_to_groups

# migration
def change
  add_column :groups, :group_members_count, :integer, default: 0
end

class GroupMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group, counter_cache: true
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_members
  scope :order_by_group_members_count, order('group_members_count DESC')
end

Group.order_by_group_members_count # => What you're looking for
```

Only one query, only on the groups table.

**edit**

If you need to reset the group_members_count:

```
ids = Group.select(:id).map &:id
ids.each do |id|
  Group.reset_counters(id, :group_members)
end
```

(because reset_counters doesn't take an array of ids)

In future [Rails 3.2.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a382d60f6abc94b6a965525872f858e48abc00de), you will write:

```
ids = Group.pluck(:id)
```

I can't wait ;-)

Comment: Thanks but I'd like to avoid that for now for various reasons. How can this be done with Rails? Thanks

Comment: +1 for the useful reset_counters code - also didn't know about "pluck" either - nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_members

  default_scope order('(select count(1) from group_members where group_members.group_id = groups.id) desc')
end
```

Note that this creates a sub-query within your order clause, which could generate a significant SQL slowdown with many group records. If this information is used frequently, it might be better to have a counter cache as Delba suggests.