# Select all posts where comments.count >= 10

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

One Post has many comments. I would like to select all posts where comments.count is greater than 5.

Something like this: Post.all.joins(:comments).having("count >= 5")

Comment: Are you looking for the RoR code, or are you trying to write an SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a `comments_count` column to your post table, and add this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
  ..
end
```

Then when you save a post, it will update the counter. At which point the query is crazy simple:

```
Post.where("comments_count >= ?", 5).all
```

Alternatively, you can drop into pure SQL code. But man, just go counters

Related: [Rails query that sorts based on the count of a nested model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407939/rails-query-that-sorts-based-on-the-count-of-a-nested-model)